# Modify link before sending request (with Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My issue is that I have some links on the page, which at the moment are ruby-generated in html file.
So, when user loads page, links are created and based on some database data. But, there is also one option, that is not DB-generated, and should work in the real time.

For example, if button 'A' is submited currently, links should request:

`http://url/?(ruby generated parametrs)&button=A`.

Then user clicks button 'B', and links request:

`http://url/?(ruby generated parametrs)&button=B`

To sum it up, basically, Jquery should add one additional parametr to link, and then send request to server.

Is this possible? How can I do that?

P.S. I strongly dislike idea of reloading all links on the page on submitting one of options button, it is connected with specific app functions, there are A LOT of such links on the page.

Code:

```
 array[i]="<span id='width_measure_#{i}'>"+(link_to(array[i], {:controller =>'tests',  :action => 'add_key', :keyword => array[i], :position=>i}, :class=>'unsaved_links', :id=>i, :method => :post, :remote => true))
```

HTML output:

```
<a href="/tests/46/add_key?keyword=TEST&amp;position=0" class="unsaved_links" data-method="post" data-remote="true" id="0" rel="nofollow">TEST</a>
```

Wanted eventual request:

```
<a href="/tests/46/add_key?keyword=TEST&amp;position=0&amp;button=A" class="unsaved_links" data-method="post" data-remote="true" id="0" rel="nofollow">TEST</a>
```

Comment: How do your links look like?

Comment: please provide the relevant code.

Comment: @amrinder007, It is ruby code, will it be relevant here?

Comment: i mean the javascript code. how are you making call....submit or ajax?

Comment: @JoeHalfFace Where comes the `A`/`B` from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following. [DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/FVsuN/1/)

**HTML**

```
<a id="buttonA" href="http://yahoo.com" target="_blank">Yahoo</a>
<a id="buttonB" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
<a id="buttonC" href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank">twitter</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('a').each(function(){

    var newUrl = $(this).attr('href') + '?button=' + this.id;
    $(this).attr('href', newUrl);

});
```

Comment: @JoeHalfFace I don't recommened this solution, since all links on your page are modified, even these who are not used, can bring bad performance if you've a lot of links...

Comment: @yckart You are right, OP can change selector as per their requirement.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is a simple replacement, or rather an string-appending:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    this.href += "&button=" + this.id;
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/N2Yvv/

Comment: So the main point of me asking this question, doest this approach send request and **after** modifies link, or it modifies link and then sends reques?

Comment: @JoeHalfFace It modifies the link and sends then the request to the server.

Comment: @JoeHalfFace Thanks too! :) I hope you read my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976760/modify-link-before-sending-request-with-jquery/16976830?noredirect=1#comment24522582_16976827?